# How do i submit a form only if all of its fields are filled in

Tags: jquery

I have the following function to check the fields. I want to submit only if all those fields are not empty

```
function validateAdminInput() {

    $('.mand').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border','solid red 1px');
        }else{
             $(this).css('border','');
        }
    });

    $('#addproducts_form').submit();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function validateAdminInput() {
    var errors = 0;
    $('.mand').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border','solid red 1px');
            errors++;
        }else{
             $(this).css('border','');
        }
    });
    if(errors === 0) {
        $('addproducts_form').trigger('submit');
    }

}
```

Comment: An ingenious solution indeed! I never thought of using a flag (`var errors`).

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateAdminInput() {
    var isValid=true;
    $('.mand').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border','solid red 1px');
            isValid=false;
        }else{
             $(this).css('border','');
        }
    });
    if(isValid)
    {
       $('#addproducts_form').submit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use some jquery validation plugin. It will allow to validate many ways.[here is link for one](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

Answer (score 1):

in your form tag, write

```
onsubmit="return checkmyform(this);"
```

and add this after the  tag:

```
function checkmyform(form){
   var $myform = $(form);
   $(".mand",myform).each(function(){
      if($(this).name()=="input"){
          if($.trim($(this).val())=="") return false;
      }else{
          if($.trim($(this).text())=="") return false;
      }
   });
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateAdminInput() {
    var error = false;
    $('.mand').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            error = true;
            $(this).css('border','solid red 1px');
        }else{
             $(this).css('border','');
        }
    });
    if(!error) $('#addproducts_form').submit();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this help you?

```
 function validateAdminInput() {
        var check = false;
        $('.mand').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                check = true;
                $(this).css('border','solid red 1px');
            }else{
                 $(this).css('border','');
            }
        });

      if(!check)
      {
      // your code
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your function, this should do it:

```
function validateAdminInput() {

    var allValid = true;

    $('.mand').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border','solid red 1px');
            allValid = false;
        }else{
             $(this).css('border','');
        }
    });

    if (allValid)
        $('#addproducts_form').submit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `required` attribute to all the fields, but this only works in browsers that support HTML5 forms.

For others, it's easy:

```
<form action="..." method="..." onSubmit="return validate(this);">
    <!-- input fields here -->
</form>
```

Also make sure to add the `required` attribute to any required field. Then...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(form) {
        var inputs, len, i;
        if( document.querySelectorAll) {
            inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[required], select[required], textarea[required]');
        }
        else {
            inputs = [];
            var tags = ['input','select','textarea'], tag, elms;
            while( tag = tags.shift()) {
                elms = form.getElementsByTagName(tag);
                len = elms.length;
                for( i=0; i<len; i++) if( elms[i].getAttribute("required")) inputs.push(elms[i]);
            }
        }
        len = inputs.length;
        for( i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if( inputs[i].value == '') {
                alert("Please fill out all fields");
                // customise error stuff here
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Note that this solution is in raw JS and is therefore guaranteed to be many times faster than any jQuery solution.